# Can I start Zoom video meeting through the java codenameone mobile app?

Tags: codenameone

I would like to start a video conference/ meeting through my java codenameone mobile app. 
Can I integrate zoom video calling features in my app?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to open a zoom URL using `Display.execute(url)` which will launch it in a cross platform way. I'm sure there are ways to integrate it deeper but I'll need to understand what you're trying to do to help further.

If you wish to integrate the SDK check out the [integrating 3rd party SDKs](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-1.html) feature on our blog which is also discussed in the developer guide. You generally wrap the sdk with a cn1lib, you can look at [existing cn1libs](https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html) for samples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I am looking for integration of zoom sdk (from zoom.us) into codenameone app to start a video conference as a host where you can use native camera and mic. Seems zoom has not made available the sdk for Java as they are providing sdk for Android, iOS etc. By integrating Zoom SDk into my codenameone app I can provide rich UI to the user also can have a full control over the zoom client sdk to utilize other features as well. 
Ref: https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/introduction

Comment: Added a paragraph about that

Comment: Thanks will try it out. Would like to know if you have any plans to provide the wrapper for Zoom SDK out of the box in near future in codenameone? Am asking this as in the current pandemic situation Zoom meetings are being widely used across the world.

Comment: Thanks in advance would like to hear from you.

Comment: Not at the moment. We have a lot of work with requests from our enterprise subscribers

Comment: Ok. Appreciate your quick assistance. Thanks a lot.